# Rails - How do you link two existing records in a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

So say I have a relationship as follows.

```
class TextbookAssociation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :textbook
    belongs_to :course
end

class Textbook < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :textbook_associations
    has_many :courses, through: :textbook_associations
end

class Course< ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :textbook_associations
    has_many :textbooks, through: :textbook_associations
end
```

If I have both a textbook and a course already in the database in their respective tables, is there a way to link them?

The only way I know how to do it is when you are creating one of the objects. Say I have a course made and then to make a textbook for that course I do

```
course.textbooks.build(params)
course.save;
```

and that will create the textbook as well as link it to the course in the TextbookAssociation table.

But what If the course and the textbook already exist? I couldn't find anything on it through my online searches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I was trying to find out how to do this I scoured the internet to find out how with queries like "Rails how to link two records in a many to many relationship". All of the results just came up with how to actually make relationships within the models, not how to use them.

While writing this question I randomly recalled the `<<` operator for arrays. I didn't remember exactly what it did but I figured it appended to an array and then I would just need to save it. So I tried it.

```
course.textbooks << textbook
```

What I found is that this actually adds the textbook to the association and saves it all in one go. That's it. Easy! I just wish I would've been able to find something about this on Google.

Later I looked up the `CollectionProxy`'s doc and found the `<<` operator here: [RoRDocs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-3C-3C)

I should have probably looked there sooner but being a Rails newb I didn't think about it.

I hope this question will show up in some Google search results so that this can help some struggling people like me.

Comment: Thanks butddy. What you say is true. Everything that pops up in google is about how to create the relationships but so few how to use them.  Thank you for pointing to the actual docs, Cheers.